# Crear un sitio web con busqueda relacionada

Tags: php, java, mysql, sql, angularjs

Buenas a todos.
Quiero saber que necesitaría para crear una web que almacene los precios actuales y actualizados de diferentes páginas web conocidas.
Estoy haciendo un proyecto y necesito ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenida a SOe. Por desgracia, tu pregunta es definitivamente *demasiado amplia*, y para responderte podrían ser necesarios varios libros. Visita [help] y [ask]; este sitio es para responder a preguntas concretas de programación (cómo hacer una tarea específica, encontrar un problema en un fragmento pequeño de código) y normalmente sobre la base del código que ya has escrito(o encontrado) tú.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día. Para recolectar información de otras páginas (web scraping), te recomiendo usar CURL. Incluso puedes saltar CAPTCHAS (yo lo hago con el de google). Por supuesto luego debes procesar la información que tomes y almacenarla. Acá te dejo un pequño ejemplo.

```
$ch1 = curl_init('string_url');
$options1 = array(CURLOPT_POST => true,
                     CURLOPT_HEADER => $request_headers,
                     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,                     
                     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => (Si vas a enviar parametros)
                    );
curl_setopt_array($ch1, $options1);
$page = curl_exec($ch1); 

if(curl_exec($ch1) === false)
{
    \print_r(curl_error($ch1));
    //Posibles Errores
}

curl_close($ch1);
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->substituteEntities = false;
//Load Document Object Model
$dom->loadHTML($page); 
$domxPath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

$urls = $domxPath->query("/html/body//div[@class='precios']"); 
//Esta linea final es donde debes buscar el contenedor que tiene la
//información que te interesa.
```

Comment: Para más información de como usar CURL. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas básicamente conocimientos de:

- php
- html
- javascript
- mysql
- servidores gnu/linux
- puede que bash y otros lenguajes o utilidades

Básicamente tienes que crear una estructura html con su diseño css y por medio de javascript y llamadas ajax, haces peticiones a un php que devolverá los datos a mostrar por ejemplo por json desde una base de datos mysql.

Lógicamente tienes que llenar la base de datos con datos recogidos por medio de bots que lanzarás desde un cron y probablemente los tendrás que programar con mezclas de php y bash y puede que otras utilidades.

Como ves es complejo y necesitas dominar muchas técnicas así que te recomiendo que busques proyectos ya hechos que se asemejen a lo que buscas y los adaptes.

Por ejemplo, puedes instalar un Drupal y realizar todo por medio de los plugins que existen (busca por scraping para la recolección de datos, igual tienes que hacer tu esa parte).

Comment: Muchas gracias track3r!  Tengo conocimientos en Php, mysql, html, css y javascript, wordpress y joomla.

Comment: No conozco muy a fondo joomla, pero puede que también puedas hacerlo aunque desde luego, deberás conocerlo muy profundamente. Desde wordpress si se puede, pero desde luego te recomiendo drupal, aunque nuevamente deberás conocerlo a fondo y la parte de recolección de datos, no creo que puedas hacerla desde ningún gestor en concreto sin amplios conocimientos, aunque hay plugins destinados a arañar otras webs en busca de datos que podrías intentar adaptar a tus necesidades. En cualquier caso, necesitar tratar con módulos o plugins del gestor que elijas y muy probablemente adaptarlos.

Comment: Mira por ejemplo https://www.drupal.org/project/restclient y suerte con los captchas ;)

Comment: Me encantaría mantener contacto contigo para cualquier duda, tienes alguna red social donde podría pedirte ayuda si me surge alguna fuera de esta plataforma web?

Comment: Estoy por aquí, pero si quieres ayuda de mi o de mis compañeros, plantea tus dudas de forma que cumplan con las normas de este sitio.

Comment: Genial, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Yo, en lugar de currarte un software entero tú, te recomiendo que pierdas el tiempo en mirar algunas herramientas que ya hacen eso. Se llaman crawlers.

Hay muchísimos. Si sabes php, este te puede ir bien: http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/example.html

Pero si buscas crawler en google verás la cantidad ingente de herramientas que hay.

Comment: muchas gracias Iker!